# AJAX stops executing before the end of the script

Tags: php, ajax

I have an AJAX class that asynchronously check for token on a form.

The actual functionality is that after checking to see it the Token exists, it should delete the existing token and create another

**Here is the PHP script:**

```
if (Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
        Session::delete($tokenName);
        return true;
    }
```

It will go through the first line, when it gets to the second line, it deletes the token but does not return true. If i comment out the `Session::delete($tokenName);` line, it will return true.

If I invert the code i.e `return true;` before `Session::delete($tokenName);` it will return true but not delete the session.

Can someone help me out as to what the problem is. Thanks.

---

**Edited:** Below is the method in the Session class

```
public static function delete($name)
    {
        if (self::exists($name)) {
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }
    }
```

**The Entire function:**

```
public static function check($token)
    {
        $tokenName = Config::get('session/token_name');

        if (Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
        Session::delete($tokenName);
        return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**My AJAX snippit:**

```
var ajax = new AjaxRequest("POST", "php-script", params, function (responseText, responseStatus) {
    var response = JSON.parse(responseText);

});
```

**This is the PHP script that receives the AJAX post:**

```
if (Token::check('token')) {
    //The first snippet should run, delete the token and return true (That's where my problem comes from)
    //If it returns true after deleting the token, this script should continue but since it is not *i'm stuck*
}
```

Comment: Nope!!! i am not using any framework whatsoever. That's if i know what fuelphp mean actually

Comment: When you "return" any code after that does not execute, this is the reason why if you put code before the return it is not processed. I think that the "Session::delete()" return something (that is not "true") so the "return true;" isn't processed.

Comment: It actually deleted the session

Comment: I see the "delete" function and it's all ok. Do you use the piece of code with the return in a function? Can you post the entire function?

Comment: Edited as requested.

Comment: No one is helping? #crying

Comment: I tried all and it works for me.

Comment: Do you check the `return true;` with `if (Token::check('token'))`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, `if (Token::check('token'))` is the same as `if (Token::check('token') === true)` right? But the issue is that it does not get to the `return true` line. It stops at `Session::delete('token')`

Comment: Yes it's the same. So for what you use ajax?

Comment: I don't understand your question sir

Comment: How you use ajax? What ajax have to do? Maybe your ajax script call the php file with `if (Token::check('token')) {`, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. AJAX calls the PHP script `if (Token::check('token')) {` but when it get to `Session::delete('token')` its stops and does not get to the next line which is `return true` so the whole process stops.

Comment: Try to see if some errors occurred. You can put `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your script to enable the report of all type of errors.

Comment: My thought is that it doesn't actually delete the token the second time, but the token is already unset and you don't actually enter the if statement at all, since `exists` fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem exists with your php code.
But if you want to pass the return value / message to ajax then you have to echo the result at the end of php file.
As you are using ajax echo return value in json format as:
echo "{'status':1}"; 
Then use your response variable in ajax as:
response.status

Comment: It worked perfectly thanks but having something like this
`public static function check($token)
 {
  $tokenName = Config::get('token/token_name');

  if (Session::exists($tokenName) && $token === Session::get($tokenName)) {
   Session::delete($tokenName);
   return true;
   exit();
  }

  return false;
  exit();
 }`
Is it right the way i `exit()` twice or i should just put it at the end of the function.